# Method visibility + inheritance + closures

Tags: php, php-5.6

Is the behavior below a bug on php-5.6.x, or is this the expected outcome?
A child class is calling the parent, and the parent tries - via a closure - to instantiate a different child having a protected constructor.

```
<?php 

class Child extends Base
{
    static function f()
    {
        parent::f(); // fails on php-5.6.x, doesn't fail on php-7.x

        // Base:f(); // doesn't fail on php-5.6.x
    }
}

class Base
{
    static function f()
    {
        Tr::inTr(
            function()
            {
                new Sibling();
            }
        );
    }
}

class Sibling extends Base
{
    protected function __construct()
    {
        echo 'I am protected';
    }
}

class Tr
{
    static function inTr($cb)
    {
        $cb();
    }
}

Child::f();
```

Output on v5.6.x:

```
Fatal error: Call to protected AnotherChild::__construct() from context 'Child'
```

But it doesn't fail on php-7.x as it can call that protected constructor.